# How can I make this DIV transparent?

Tags: css

[image]

I have give a shape to this but when I place it on a header white background of div come I want to make that div transparent. i just want the back white div to be transparent

```
.shape{
height:300px;
background:#1EC8D7;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:999;
}
.shape:after,.shape:before{
content:"";
position:absolute;
background:#FFF;
height:200px;
width:110%;
}
div:before{
bottom:100%;

transform-origin:0 100%;
-ms-transform-origin:100% 0;
-webkit-transform-origin:0 100%;

transform:rotate(3deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
 }
.shape:after{
top:100%;
 transform-origin:0 0;
-ms-transform-origin:0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;

transform:rotate(-5deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-5deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
 }
```

Comment: could you post a picture of the expected result? maybe also create a http://jsfiddle.net with what you have got now (markup is missing here)

Comment: this is want i am looking for placing a div over banner?the green one is a div with some css rotations                                ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rHrx6.jpg

Comment: ok click here http://jsfiddle.net and then paste all the releveant code there. help us help you, we need you HTML markup cause I don't want to write it for you if you already have done it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cCFS4/    here it is check it